# casting to int in c#

Tags: c#

I read that casting will throw an exception if the cast doesn't go through and that there's a better syntax to cast which return a null instead of an exception if the cast is not possible. But I forgot it. Any refresher?
thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is what you're looking for...

```
string s = "36";
int resultInt;    
int.TryParse(s, out resultInt);
```

Answer (score 8):

I think you are referring to the `as` cast. However `as` cannot be used on non-reference types so you cannot do `int x = obj as int`.

In order to parse an `int` or some other value-type you can use the type specific trycast methods..

```
int x;
bool success = int.TryParse(someString, out x);
```

Answer (score 1):

if it's originating from a string, you can always use a TryParse()

```
if(!Int.TryParse(s, out i))
    (handle non-int code here)
```

Answer (score 1):

In c# if you use

```
int x = Convert.toInt32(string)
```

it internally calls int.tryparse as the convert method is a static wrapper class for tryparse. I find it a bit cleaner to use, though it is in theory a bit slower.

Comment: `Convert.ToInt32` still throws on invalid inputs. If he's looking for exception-free behavior, this is not it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "as" operator on reference types.  But since an int can be null, you can't use that operator.  So for a string object to string cast you could do this:

```
 object o = "";
 string s = o as string;
```

But couldn't do the same with an int.

Answer (score 0):

What your looking for is the `as`

So `int myCasted = myVar as int;`

Which apparently won't work on non-nullable value types

Comment: this won't compile, can't use `As` on a value type

Comment: @Eric Lippert, that's actually what I meant, fixing